# Select unique records in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite, select

Consider a table

results (id, key, value) where key is the Primary key.

Sample data:

```
id | key      | value
-----------------------
abc| source-1 | 20
abc| source-2 | 30
abc| source-3 | 2 
abc| source-4 | 10
def| source-5 | 1 
ghi| source-6 | 25
jkl| source-5 | 13
```

I would like to return only those records which have a single entry for a given id. So output should be

```
id | key      | value
------------------------
def| source-5 | 1
ghi| source-6 | 25
jkl| source-5 | 13
```

Please advise.

Comment: How can `key` be the primary key, if there are duplicate values (`source-5`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to use GROUP BY and HAVING to produce a derived table with the desired `id`s and then JOIN to it:

```
select results.*
from results
join (
    select id
    from results
    group by id
    having count(*) = 1
) as dt on results.id = dt.id
```

You could also use an IN if you don't like derived tables:

```
select *
from results
where id in (
    select id
    from results
    group by id
    having count(*) = 1
)
```

Comment: Is the sub-query actually required here? Testing with the data from the question SQLite3 gives me the right result just for `SELECT id, key, value FROM t GROUP BY id HAVING count(*) == 1;`. My SQL-fu isn't strong enough to know if that will always work though.

Comment: @JohnBartholomew: Not for SQLite (and MySQL) but yes for most other databases. If you don't use a derived table to produce just the `id`s you want, a lot of databases will complain about selecting unaggregated and ungrouped columns. Things like `select a, b from t group by a` are ambiguous (which `b` should you choose for duplicate `a`s?) so many databases complain, some just quietly grab a `b`. Most databases would complain about the `==` too.