# Check if the row already exist in database in android

Tags: android, sqlite, registration

please help me. I'm trying to make a registration app that will save consumer's data. The user needs to enter his complete name together with the company he wants to register to. He can register many times as long as it is in different company. My problem in my code below is that the program only compare the user input on the first data he enter. for example, the user enter his name and the company is ABC, the program accept it, when the user enter again his name and the company is DEF the program still accept it, but when the user enter his name and the company DEF again the program still accept it which is wrong, when you change the company in ABC the program did not accept it. So what I see is that my code only comparing the data on the first info entered.

here's my code:

in my databaseAdapter

```
public Constructor getNameCp(String name) 
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Constructor consName = new Constructor();
    try 
    { 
        Cursor c = db.query(Constants.DATABASE_TABLE_CONSUMER,null, Constants.CONSUMER_FULLNAME + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(name)},null, null, null);                                               
        if (c == null) 
        {                        
            return consName;                                   
        }

        else{    
            c.moveToFirst();               
            consName = new Constructor(Integer.parseInt(c.getString(0)),c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Constants.CONSUMER_EMPNO)),c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Constants.CONSUMER_FULLNAME)), c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Constants.CONSUMER_CELLPHONENO)), c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Constants.CONSUMER_COMPANY)));
        }                   
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return consName; 
}
```

in my activity

```
String name = databaseAdapter.getNameCp(fullName).getConsumerFullname();
String comp = databaseAdapter.getNameCp(fullName).getCompanyname();

if ((fullName.equals(name)) && (companyName.equals(comp))){
    UpdateByEmployeeName(fullName);
    Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, "Account info already exist.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}else{
    String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
    databaseAdapter.SaveConsumerDetails(new Constructor(Emp.toUpperCase(), Lastname, Firstname, Middlename.toUpperCase(), Cp, Email, fullName, careFriend, companyName, emailmark, currentDateandTime, consumerId, consumercompanycode));
refresh();
}
```

Comment: provide your create table query so i can help you..

Comment: i'm using a preloaded database.

Comment: have you got valid name and comp from database from first two lines.??

Comment: yes. but comp only get the company name that was entered first.

Comment: @lolliloop you can prevent duplicate entries to the column by havaing  aunique contraint for the column required

Comment: ahmn no. I allow duplication of entry in my program. company ABC can be saved again but it should  be with different name of user.

Comment: @lolliloop try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12613062/select-unique-records-in-sqlite or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790162/sqlite-select-disticnt-values-of-a-column-without-ordering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below method in your database class for getting list of all companies for particular employee name:

```
public ArrayList<String> getCompName(String name) {

    ArrayList<String> alCompNm = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select CompName FROM projsitemast where Name='"+name+"'", null);
        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
            for (int j = 0; j < c.getCount(); j++) {
                alCompNm.add(c.getString(0));
                System.out.println("Client Site Name : " + c.getString(0));
                c.moveToNext();
            }
            c.close();
        }
        return alCompNm;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return alCompNm;
}
```

In your Main Activity:

```
flag = 0;
ArrayList<String> cNm = new ArrayList<String>();
dba.open();
cNm = dba.getCompName(yourname);

for(int i=0;i< cNm.size();i++){
   String cmpname = cNm.get(i).toString();

   if(cmpname.equals(yourcmpname)){
           flag = 1;
      }
}

if(flag==0){
String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
    databaseAdapter.SaveConsumerDetails(new Constructor(Emp.toUpperCase(), Lastname, Firstname, Middlename.toUpperCase(), Cp, Email, fullName, careFriend, companyName, emailmark, currentDateandTime, consumerId, consumercompanycode));
refresh();
// OR as per your requirement
}
else{
Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, "Account info already exist.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```